# Old names in content even with using \renewcommand

Tags: table-of-contents, french

I am writing a document in latex in French. I used the \renewcommand to rename titles like: "Table of figures" to "Table des figures" and "List of tables" to "Liste des tableaux". The names change in their own pages (in the page listing the tables, the title is "Liste des tableaux" as I renamed it) but in the contents, it still has the old name in English ("List of tables"). Can anyone help me with that please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tableaux}
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}
  \lhead{\emph{Table des matières}}
  \tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents
  \lhead{\emph{Liste des figures}}
  \listoffigures
  \lhead{\emph{Liste des tableaux}}
  \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Did you run `latex` twice? And is it really a `latex3` question as you tagged it?

Comment: You will find an MWE below. Yes I run latex twice and sorry, it's not a latex3 question. I just changed the tags. Thank you for your time.

\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tableaux}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Liste des figures}

\lhead{\emph{Table des matières}}
\tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents

\lhead{\emph{Liste des figures}} 
\listoffigures 

\lhead{\emph{Liste des tableaux}}
\listoftables

\end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do ids loading `babel` with the `french` option — as a `document option`, I recall, since version 3 of frenchb. You don't have to rename whatever: `frenchb` does it for you::

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, french]{Thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents

  \listoffigures
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}


 \listoftables
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

%  \clearpage
 \chapter{Chapitre Premier}
 \lipsum[1-6]

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the result of the code you just sent.  http://s14.directupload.net/images/140808/lvbqtehc.jpg

Comment: This is *not* the result of my code, since I didn't mention abbreviations, symbols, &c. You incorporated my code into your code and there's certainly an interaction. What was your preamble?

Comment: Yes sorry i incorporated your code in mine. Your code here gives the same result you shared, but when I put it with mine it give the result above. The preamble is:
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage[binary]{SIunits}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

Comment: You forgot `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Anyway, with your preamble, I get the same result. So it must be something else. You should comment (with the `comment` environment) all of your files, except the lines above up to `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}`. Compiling should produce what you expect. Then uncomment progressively until  the names are in english. This way you'll locate the error source. Still: is there really nothing else in the preamble (I think of personal macros, or package options that might switch to the english language).

Comment: I located the source of the problem, it's a latex class file that I downloaded with the source of the project. I shall try to figure it out, I will post again if I find something else.

Comment: I found the problem. The class file with the downloaded project contained the following code:

    \renewcommand\listoffigures{
    \btypeout{List of Figures}
    \addtotoc{List of Figures}

By changing the last line to \addtotoc{Liste des figures} the problem was solved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You also simply could comment this line. Anyway that's a happy end!